# Ubuntu on Asus motherboard

Tags: system-installation, asus, support, motherboard

I am planning to get myself a new motherboard (Asus PRIME B365) and the official website didn't say anything about Linux distros. So I was wondering does Asus motherboards support Linux? If anyone has experience with Asus motherboards and share it, I would be really glad :)

Comment: *Shopping or Hardware Recommendations* are off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), Ubuntu Forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/) would I believe be a better place for this sort of *opinionated* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this PDF from Asus](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report_201911.pdf), Ubuntu and others are supported:

[image: Asus B365 Compatibility]

Be sure to update to the latest firmware to ensure the best compatibility, and happy building

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have dual boot system of 'Windows 10" and Ubuntu 20.04 latest version in my ASUS Motherboard...
My Motherboard is "P7H55-M LE Series"
I am also new to Ubuntu Linux Family.